# Images not appearing on local host

Tags: html, image, localhost

Images are not appearing on my local host. Here is HTML code. I've tried several variations to display te images. Twitter Bootstrap is used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="">
  <img class="media-object" src="/img/grads.jpg/64x64">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
  <h4 class="media-heading">Collaborate with students at other Universities</h4>
  <p>Join your classes and work with other students on studying without having to meet up.</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="">
  <img class="media-object" src="grads.jpeg/64x64">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
  <h4 class="media-heading">Meet new friends you're in class with</h4>
  <p>Pick who you want to be a stranger in your own classes. School is social and so is moreo. : )</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  /* Custom container */
  .container-narrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  .container-narrow > hr {
    margin: 30px 0;
  }

  /* Main marketing message and sign up button */
  .jumbotron {
    margin: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .jumbotron h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .jumbotron .btn {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  /* Supporting marketing content */
  .marketing {
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  .marketing p + h4 {
    margin-top: 14px;
  }
</style>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: you are able to see images via IP? and what is /64x64 at end of image path?

Comment: If you have Chrome or Firebug, do you see the HTTP request being sent for the image files and if so, are they returned?

Comment: Also, when you say localhost, do you mean a local LAMP stack or do you mean html-only file:// scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Try to view source and check for the paths of the images. Since you have used relative paths, Check whether the correct path for the image is taken or not on local

Answer (score 0):

Verify your images path. it should end with file-name and its proper extension.

See you have,

```
<img class="media-object" src="grads.jpeg/64x64">
```

This could be like this, i think;

```
<img class="media-object" src="/64x64/grads.jpeg">
```

Now, if the image (grads.jpeg) is available in root's 64x64 folder, that will definitely render.

Answer (score 0):

use [Bootstrap image](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#images) for image loading and media object use `data-src` attribute not `src` but i did not see any example of loading image with direct image URL [Bootstrap Media object](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#media)

**EDIT**

i think this tag refers online url, i am not sure. take a look at this [placehold](http://placehold.it/) this URL is utility site which re-size the hosted image just like bootstrap example

Comment: <div class="media">
      <a class="pull-left href="#">
      <img class="media-object" data-src="/img/marvin.jpg">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Heading</h4>
      <div class="media">
      <p>This is the text you can place next to the image.</p>  
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

Comment: even with the code above, the image does not populate. The img folder is in my directory with all the images in it. I have tried dozens of iterations.